# Cannot resolve symbol 'BaseLoaderCallback'. After installing the OpenCV 4.9.0

Tags: java, android, opencv, gradle

I am trying to use BaseLoaderCallback and LoaderCallbackInterface. Maybe OpenCv 4.9.0 doesnt has it?[Some of imports added but not all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3jQT.png)
Can someone explain why am i getting this problem?
My SDK is 33. Gradle version: 8.0.2.

Comment: Upd: I am downgraded Gradle Plugin to 7.4.2, and used OpenCv 3.4.14. Now it works

Comment: But if someone know how to do it in 4.9.0 version?

Comment: Since you answered your own question, you can also post it as an answer at some point. Please do so in an answer and not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem too.
What I ended up doing was adding in the missing files from here:

https://github.com/zhu260824/OpenCV/tree/master/OpenCVLibrary/src/main/java/org/opencv/android

Which I'm assuming is using an older version of the OpenCV library.

There are three files that I ended up adding:

```
BaseLoaderCallback.java

InstallCallbackInterface.java

LoaderCallbackInterface.java
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question can be found in the [OpenCV change log for version 4.9.0](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#user-content-version490). In the Android section it states:

> Finally removed API for OpenCV manager. OpenCVLoader.initLocal() should be used to initialize OpenCV.

TL;DR: Remove the outdated `BaseLoaderCallback` and `LoaderCallbackInterface` references and instead call `OpenCVLoader.initLocal()` in the `onCreate` and make sure you call the `enableView()` and `disableView()` methods where necessary (e.g. from `onResume`, `onPause` etc.).

Very simple example you can see in [this sample code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/android/tutorial-1-camerapreview/src/org/opencv/samples/tutorial1/Tutorial1Activity.java).